# Resist activity to come in Foreground after SCREEN_ON [Android]

Tags: java, android

I have an android application in which I am doing one function on SCREEN_OFF. Now when I again SCREEN_ON, I see my activity again coming in foreground which I don't want. I tried [finish()] method in [onCreate] as well [moveTaskToBack(true);] but both didn't worked.

You can think of Facebook having service running in background but when we SCREEN_ON the home screen never comes in foreground until and unless we don't open application manually.

Regards

Comment: If you don't need a gui, use a broadcast receiver instead.

Comment: Can you describe that in detail Olaf ? We have GUI screens as a part of applications. But activity is not required every time to come in front, may be it is because its life cycle is not getting killed !!

Comment: At [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) you can read an introduction, where broadcast receivers are also described. In the Android SDK samples, you will find examples using receivers.

Comment: I have used receivers but particularly handling this case is somewhat unique i never faced earlier. Anyone else can help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some action at screen off without user interaction, define a broadcast receiver and do your work there

```
public class ScreenOffActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    }
}
```

and in your manifest file define the receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenOffActionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Olaf for your help. I could resolve the issue. I tell you how i did it. I put a flag in that method where I was wanted to put

```
 Bundle myKillerBundle = new Bundle();
        myKillerBundle.putInt("kill",1);
        intent.putExtras(myKillerBundle);
```

and onCreate of Activity, I am checking that flag

```
 if(this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kill")==1){
            Log.d("ACTIVITY_TAG", "Yes got the flag");
            moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Now whenever that flag will be true it will call the activity and push it to background